# How does " virtual" keyword work in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to understand 'virtual' keyword along with function.

I've got some experiment as the below,

```
  class A ; 
         function void disp (); 
          $display(" Non-Virtual from A "); 
        endfunction
        virtual function void vdisp (); 
          $display(" Virtual from A "); 
        endfunction
      endclass 

      class EA extends A ;
          function void disp (); 
          $display(" Non-Virtual from EA "); 
        endfunction
         virtual function void vdisp (); 
          $display(" Virtual from EA "); 
        endfunction
      endclass 

    module main ; 

      function void disp( A a);
        a.disp();
        a.vdisp();
      endfunction

        A my_a; 
        EA my_ea;


      initial 
      begin 
        my_a = new(); 
        my_ea = new(); 

        disp(my_a); 
        disp(my_ea); 

      end 
    endmodule
```

and I've got the below message from code,

```
Non-Virtual from A 
 Virtual from A 
 Non-Virtual from A 
 Virtual from EA
```

But my expectation is that should be like this,

```
 Non-Virtual from A 
 Virtual from A 
 Non-Virtual from EA 
 Virtual from EA
```

What does " vitual" keyword  work in systemverilog?

Would you please explain why do I get this result? and how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have constructed two object, one of type `A` whose handle is stored in `my_a`, and the other of type `EA` whose handle is stored in `my_ea`. When you call `disp(my_ea)`, you are upcasting the `EA` handle to the function argument class variable `a` of type `A`.

When you call a non-virtual function, it uses the fixed class type `A` of the class variable `a` to choose which method gets called. So `function A::disp` gets called.

When you call a virtual function, the dynamic type of the class handle `EA` stored in the class variable `a` is used to choose which method gets called. So `EA::disp` gets called.

Comment: data_59, I undersatnd it. Thanks. BTW, What if I use Virtual keyword to class not function, then does it have the same meaning?

Comment: Related but not the same meaning, See **8.21 Abstract classes and pure virtual methods** in the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM

Answer (score 0):

In other words: virtual function is a special type of function that, when called, executes the “most” child method that exists between the parent and child classes. This property is also known as polymorphism. The child method is called when the signature (name, parameter types, and whether the method is a constant) and return type of the child method match the signature and return type of the parent class method. Such methods are called overrides (or "overridden methods"). Because of `class EA extends A` , you got `Virtual from EA` ,as  `EA` `s method most child)